# Assessment is "failing" under id 5, Reallocated Sector Count, whose value comes out to be 561 sectors

Tags: hard-drive, smart

I repeatedly receive a message from **Disk Utility** on screen, which says "A Hard Disk is reporting health problems."

On clicking the Examine button, I am taken towards a window,which says **Disk failure is imminent**

On viewing SMART Data and running self tests I was taken to new window which shows "564 bad sectors on top right hand corner, and also says that "back up all data and replace the disk"

I tried to various commands to run disk repairing wizard, but unfortunately every time, a pop up window with warning regarding bad health of drive appears and nothing happens.

System is core i3 with 2GB RAM and 320GB hard disk with following description,

1. on writing `sudo fdisk -lu` it prints

   ```
   Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
   255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
   Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   Disk identifier: 0x000e4a21

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
   /dev/sda1   *        2048   104859647    52428800    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
   /dev/sda2       104859648   314574847   104857600    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
   /dev/sda3       314574848   551428095   118426624    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
   /dev/sda4       551430142   625141759    36855809    5  Extended
   /dev/sda5       551430144   621228031    34898944   83  Linux
   /dev/sda6       621230080   625141759     1955840   82  Linux swap / Solaris
   ```
2. on writing, `root@ubuntu:~# sudo fsck -y /dev/sda5` I got:

   ```
   fsck from util-linux 2.19.1
   e2fsck 1.41.14 (22-Dec-2010)
   /dev/sda5: clean, 137141/2182992 files, 708304/8724736 blocks
   ```
3. on writing, `root@ubuntu:~# sudo fsck -pcfv /dev/sda5` I got:

   ```
   fsck from util-linux 2.19.1
   /dev/sda5: Updating bad block inode.

   137141 inodes used (6.28%)
     18 non-contiguous files (0.0%)
    106 non-contiguous directories (0.1%)
        # of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 0/0/0
        Extent depth histogram: 109527/3
   708304 blocks used (8.12%)
      0 bad blocks
      1 large file

   84575 regular files
   13613 directories
     57 character device files
     25 block device files
      0 fifos
      0 links
   38862 symbolic links (27519 fast symbolic links)
      0 sockets

   137132 files
   ```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you already "backup all your data" as advised by the SMART utility? That's the very first thing you should have done.

Answer (score -1):

The head on the drive is probably going bad. Replace the drive.

Comment: Can you expand on this?  What in the OP question backs up your statement?

Comment: Although it is good advice to replace the drive as soon as possible.